# Has an NCAA conference ever dissolved?

Tags: collegiate

With all the reshuffling of teams in college sports, for instance Rutgers and Maryland to the Big Ten, I was wondering if there was a past NCAA conference that has ever dissolved? Because I see this possibly happening to the Big East with all the changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Big 8 and the Southwest Conference.  A combination of teams from both ended up in the Big 12.

Comment: What are the history of these conferences? Why did they end up in the Big 12?

Answer (score 3):

This has happened fairly often, actually; Sports-Reference.com lists [twenty-one defunct conferences](http://www.sports-reference.com/cbb/conferences/) versus thirty-three active conferences.  I don't know much about the specific histories of the conferences, unfortunately.

The most recent dissolved conference is the Great West Conference, dissolved after the 2013 season.